# Why doesn't Magento 2.1 support PHP 7.0.3 to 7.0.5?

Tags: magento2, php, php-7, magento-2.1

As you may know [Magento 2.1.0](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.0CE.html#system-requirements) is out.

According to the release notes, only PHP 7.0.2 AND PHP 7.0.6 are supported

[image]

Why aren't PHP 7.0.3 / 7.0.4 / 7.0.5 supported ?

Edit: [2.1.2 now supports PHP 7.0.4](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.2CE.html#highlights)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No official information but this Github issue gives a hint:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4070

> **alankent** commented on 8 Apr
>
> Could you try 7.0.4? There are reports of something breaking with
> 7.0.5. Not sure who's fault, but 7.0.5 is behaving differently in a way that impacts Magento.

...

> **Vinai** commented on 9 Apr
>
> @alankent Same result in PHP 7.0.4

...

> **moleman** commented 9 days ago
>
> I had the same issue when running on php 7.0.5 but it works on php
> 7.0.6

Seems like they preferred to skip compatibility for the broken patch releases of PHP instead of working around them.

Also https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2596

> **maksek** commented 9 days ago
>
> [...] we are not
> recommending using 7.0.5 due the bugs, check PHP version section -
> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html.
> Can you try to downgrade or upgrade PHP from 7.0.5 and check again?

From that doc page:

> #### PHP
>
> - 5.6.x
> - 5.5.x, where x is 22 or greater
> - 7.0.2–7.0.6 except for 7.0.5 (supported by Magento version 2.0.1 and later only)
>
> There is a known PHP issue that affects our code compiler when using
> PHP 7.0.5. We recommend you not use PHP 7.0.5; instead, use PHP
> 7.0.2–7.0.4 or 7.0.6.

This does not mention problems with 7.0.3 or even 7.0.4 but it's likely that there were similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.0.1 adds support for PHP 7.0.2, which provides dramatic performance improvements, drastically reduces memory consumption, and supports new PHP language features.

https://magento.com/blog/technical/new-magento-20-resources-and-support-php7