# Composer Update Error: magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6

Tags: error, upgrade, composer, php-7, magento-2.1

Trying to do an update to **Magento 2.1.0** via composer and getting this weird error.

Php version is 7.04 running on Ubuntu x64

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
```

> ./composer.json has been updated

```
composer update
```

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> **Problem 1**
>       - Installation request for *magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition*[2.1.0].
>
> *- magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that
>   requirement.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no `magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0` yet. Latest release is `magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0-rc3`. The wording in magento bulletins and notifications is misleading and tricky. You get the impression that there is a 2.1.0 GA, but there are only Release candidates.

Comment: 2.1.0 has just been released, but it is not compatible with PHP 7.0.4 because of a bug in that PHP version. This is also what the error message states.

Comment: @fschmengler are you sure 2.1.0 GA was released? I get this error if I want to update with composer `Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.1.0-rc3, 0.42.0-beta7, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.1.0-rc1, 2.1.0-rc2] but these are rejected by your constraint.`

Comment: it was announced at least, I did not try to update yet. If it's not available on repo.magento.com yet, it seems like OP hat a constraint like `stability: alpha` which made `2.1.0-rc3` match his requirement of `2.1.0`.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP version constraints of Magento 2.1 are `~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6` as shown in the error message. That means, it is compatible with all patch versions of PHP 5.6, with PHP 7.0.2 and with PHP 7.0 versions >= 7.0.6

The gap comes from some bugs in PHP 7.0.3-7.0.5 that caused problems with Magento and are fixed in 7.0.6.

**More info:** [Why doesn't Magento 2.1 support PHP 7.0.3 to 7.0.5?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116418/why-doesnt-magento-2-1-rc1-support-php-7-0-3-to-7-0-5/116427#116427)

**Solution:** Update your PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you have to completely uninstall php5 and components and then install php 7.0 using the process found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7

then make sure to install the necessary modules and you will be back in business...if you check your phpinfo.php you will probably find that even though you have installed php7 it is not the default php being used and thus you are getting that error.