# Magento 2.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 not running on PHP 7.0.4

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, error, installation

I just tried to run Magento-CE-2.1.0. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and the php version is 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.
But I got this error when I wanted to run Magento:

> 'Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read
>   Magento System Requirements.'

What should I do? Can't I run Magento on ubuntu 16?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, they have a big issue with PHP version on Ubuntu 16.04 .

Your only real option is to **change PHP version to 7.0.6 or 7.0.8** or wait for next release (they are going to fix it).

Look here for more information: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5131 .

Look here for PHP upgrade: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php?field.series_filter=xenial

**UPDATE:**

Ubuntu 16.04 has been updated to support 7.0.8, so Magento 2 is no more an issue on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that **Magento 2.1 does not support PHP from 7.0.3 to 7.0.5**. More information here: [Why doesn't Magento 2.1 support PHP 7.0.3 to 7.0.5?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116418/why-doesnt-magento-2-1-support-php-7-0-3-to-7-0-5)

As you're running 7.0.4 **you need to upgrade to at least 7.0.6 to be able to run Magento 2.1 on Ubuntu 16.**

Answer (score 0):

Using ubuntu should not make any difference.
Try running php version 7.0.4 if you can rather than 7.0.4-7 or try php 7.0.6

More information on upgrading php on ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/565961

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I believe the issue is with `composer.json`. You might be able to add 7.0.4 in `composer.json` and get it to work. We've done a lot of testing and found that 7.0.4 *does* work; however, 7.0.5 does *not* work due to a known issue in that release.